# ExtensionMacros.h: No such file or directory

Tags: cocos2d-x

Although this file exists in the extensions folder but still i get this error. I have followed many solution but struck on this error. please help me. 
In my extensions/Android.mk file I have also included

```
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/..
```

Answer (score 2):

because ExtensionMacros.h is in the path $(LOCAL_PATH)
i suggest you add "LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)"

or change to #include "extensions/ExtensionMacros.h"